# probability with exponential distribution

Tags: probability, markov-chains

there is a barber shop with two waiting chair and one barber.suggest that,when a customer comes in,and two waiting chair are full,he goes to another barber shop.

The time between entering of two customers,is an exponential random variable with `average=a`.

the need time for working on each customer,is an exponential random variable with `average=b`.

when the barber shop is empty,barber goes out from shop,for rest and after a period  of time that is an exponential random variable with `average=c`,he comes back to shop.

**what percentage of customers that arrive, do lose ,because two waiting chairs are full?**

Comment: I dont get something? if the barber goes out the shop and comes back, the shop is still empty, what does he do?

Comment: Does the barber close the shop when he goes out, or do customers wait in the chairs until he comes back?

Comment: @Henry because the shop is empty, he goes out..

Comment: You have to study the M/M/c/c queue, also known as the Erlang-$\beta$ model